# Opperations inside a list with different elements

Tags: list

The teacher assistant assigned me this problem but I could not understand if this op is possible:

1. Create a list with int, str and float: `my_list = [2, 3, 0.5, "cams"]`
2. print only the odd numbers in this list

I am not sure if I can operate conditions in a list with different elements. Please help!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: After adding the *tag*, please don't forget to post your *attempted* code and where do  you have *exact* question.  Question: what do you expect to handle the *string* item?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```py
my_list = [2, 3, 0.5, "cams"]

for i in my_list:
    if type(i) is not str and i%2 == 1:
        print(i)
```

JS:

```js
my_list = [2, 3, 0.5, "cams"]

for(let i=0;i<my_list.length;i++){
    if(typeof(my_list[i]) != "string" && i%2 == 1){
    console.log(my_list[i])
  }
}
```

Output:

`3`